# Biblatex error can't use file + pdf

Tags: biblatex, errors

For my bibliography, I'm often getting an error message like:

```
Package biblatex Warning: BibTeX reported the following issues
(biblatex)                with 'Olevsky2000':
(biblatex)                - Can't use 'file' + 'pdf'.
```

The corresponding `bibtex` entry looks like that:

```
@ARTICLE{Olevsky2000,
  author = {Olevsky, E. A. and German, R. M. and Upadhyaya, A.},
  title = {Effect of gravity on dimensional change during sintering--II. Shape
    distortion},
  journal = {Acta Materialia},
  year = {2000},
  volume = {48},
  pages = {1167--1180},
  number = {5},
  month = mar,
  file = {Olevsky2000.txt:LiteraturEinzeln/Olevsky2000.txt:Text},
  keywords = {Sintering, Gravity},
  owner = {me},
  pdf = {Olevsky2000.pdf},
  timestamp = {2007.01.02},
  url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/B6TW8-3YRVDK1-H/2/676f0bfaba8eefac654600c1c1714525}}
```

### Question:

It was quite a long time ago that I created and processed those bibliographic entries and frankly I'm not sure where the "file" information was coming from.
I'm mainly using `JabRef` for managing my bibtex files but was also sometimes experimenting with `BibDesk`.
It seems that I've attached links to a text file (but sometimes also again to the corresponding pdf) to some entries.

- what's the difference between the `file` and `pdf` field?
- what's the problem for `biblatex`, if both fields are used? (I don't see a problem so far and the content of both fields shall *not* be printed in the bibliography so could be ignored by `biblatex` IMHO)
- how can I avoid those error messages blowing up my log file?

Comment: Perhaps the errors comes from the pdf field. I don't remember that would be a valid field for bibilatex. Try to comment it and compile again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `biblatex` styles do not use `pdf` or `file` fields in the output, but the data is processed by the back-end to make it available (you might want for example a reading form of your database with hyperlinks to the PDFs). As described in the `biblatex` manual, the fields `file` and `pdf` are treated as equivalent: `file` is the 'native' name for `biblatex` with `pdf` provided as that is what JabRef uses.

In terms or a work-around, you could use the Biber back-end as it doesn't issue a warning here. (It seems to pick up `file` not `pdf`: I wonder if it *should* issue a warning!) You could though just ignore the warning: it's not a big issue. Unless you want to make use of the information in typeset output there is no need to worry. Of course, if you don't need the data you could use a BibTeX file tool to remove one or other of the fields (JabRef can certainly do this).

Comment: thanks for the explanations! Using the `biber` backend (by adding `backend=biber` to the `biblatex` options does **not**  avoid the error warning for me. For the moment I will just ignore the warnings, but  I'll try to consolidate my bibtex entries some time...

Comment: @Martin Which version of Biber do you have? I've double-checked with a clean directory and I don't get a warning with Biber 1.9.

Comment: hm, I think I've forgot to clean the directory...